# Why was there such a long gap between the parts of the "Before" Series?

Tags: production, before-midnight, before-sunrise, before-sunset

I was just wondering why there was such a long gap between the "Before" series.

Before Sunrise: 1995

Before Sunset: 2004

Before Midnight: 2013

Comment: This is explained on the relevant wiki pages.

Answer (score 6):

Ethan Hawke discussed this with [Collider](http://collider.com/ethan-hawke-on-a-3rd-before-sunrise-before-sunset-movie/):

> He also revealed, “We had a version of [Before Sunset] that happened two
>   years later.  ***But once it took us five years and we can’t get the
>   money to make that movie we have to rethink it.*** So elements or lines
>   from that script stayed.  When we first finished Before Sunset there
>   was an idea that we would do.  Julie and I wanted to do a short film
>   the next year that we thought would be really fun to do like a five
>   minute short and then put it in the vault so to speak and then fifteen
>   years later make another film.”

The article also discussed the third film:

> If you’re a fan (like me) of these two amazing movies and are hoping
>   they’d do a third film, it sounds like they aren’t against it, but
>   don’t expect to see it anytime soon.  That’s because even though
>   people constantly give Hawke ideas for the film, he says, “***My thought
>   is we will make one as soon as everybody has forgotten about it***.”

They later clarified the exact reason they released the third film when they did, in an interview with French website [Allocine](http://www.allocine.fr/article/fichearticle_gen_carticle=18608764.html). Quoting from [The Guardian's rewrite of it](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2011/nov/23/hawke-delpy-before-sunrise-sequel):

> Hawke reveals that he, Delpy and Linklater are negotiating a third
>   outing for the transatlantic couple. "All of three of us have been
>   having similar feelings that we're ready to revisit those characters,"
>   said Hawke. "***There's nine years between the first two movies and, if
>   we made the film next summer, it would be nine years again, so we
>   really started thinking that would be a good thing to do***. We're going
>   to try to write it this year."

So to summarise, they wanted to release *Before Sunset* earlier, but struggled to get funding and that delayed the launch. When they did finally release the film, nine years had passed. They didn't want to release *Before Midnight* too early, and eventually settled on releasing it nine years after *Before Sunset*, to have the same timeline consistency between the first two films as the second and third films.